# How to send post data with advanced rest client

Tags: php, rest, client

I have chrome advanced rest client plugin and am not able to send simple post data. Tried several times - no success, no idea what is wrong.

I set up php function to return:

```
   public function test() {
        echo json_encode($_POST);
        echo json_encode($_GET);
        //echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
    }
```

and in the payload field I copy such text from console from real ajax requests - form data:

```
slip_data[0][stake_amount]:1
slip_data[0][id]:736372
```

And result is only

```
[][]
```

Why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Payload you've entered has wrong structure. You need to use proper encoding.
For example, if you want to send POST data as a wwwurlencoded data it should looks like:

```
slip_data%5B0%5D%5Bstake_amount%5D=1&slip_data%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=736372
```

Other possibility is to use multipart-form data.